# How do I resolve the "Enter Parameter value" error in MS-Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, t-sql, ms-access

This code and another is producing the logical error in Ms-Access where it asks for a parameter equal to an objects name. In this case it wants [DSRT_ERS].[ID].

```
INSERT INTO DSRT_ERS
SELECT *
FROM DSRT_TEMP
WHERE  [DSRT_ERS].[ID] <>[DSRT_TEMP].[ID];
```

If you look at the DB's documentation you notice it is spelled correctly.

```
Table: DSRT_ERS                                                                                      

Properties

AlternateBackShade:       100                         AlternateBackTheme        -1
AlternateBackTint:        100                         BackShade:                100
BackTint:                 100                         DatasheetForeTheme        -1

DatasheetGridlinesTh      -1                          DateCreated:              6/17/2015 10:15:19 AM
DefaultView:              2                           DisplayViewsOnShar        1
FilterOnLoad:             False                       GUID:                     {guid {BC8AFE53-
                                                                                8AE3-42B9-AA5A-

HideNewField:             False                       LastUpdated:              6/17/2015 10:21:50 AM
NameMap:                  Long binary data            OrderByOn:                False
OrderByOnLoad:            True                        Orientation:              Left-to-Right

ReadOnlyWhenDisco         False                       RecordCount:              1022
ThemeFontIndex:           -1                          TotalsRow:                False
Updatable:                True




Columns

         Name                                                  Type                        Size
         ID                                                    Text                                   255
                  AggregateType:             -1
                  AllowZeroLength:           True

                  AppendOnly:                False
                  Attributes:                Variable Length
                  CollatingOrder:            General

                  ColumnHidden:              False
                  ColumnOrder:               Default
                  ColumnWidth:               Default
                  CurrencyLCID:              0
                  DataUpdatable:             False
                  DisplayControl:            Text Box
                  Format:                    @

                  GUID:                      {guid {A1301DB4-C42E-4B73-A84B-
                  IMEMode:                   0
                  IMESentenceMode:           3
                  OrdinalPosition:           1

                  Required:                  False
                  ResultType:                0
                  SourceField:               ID

                  SourceTable:               DSRT_ERS
                  TextAlign:                 General
                  UnicodeCompression:        False
```

I am unsure what to do at this point. A similar query produces this result(but with different parameters) and that all so needs to be fixed. If anyone could provide some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This will exclude the [DSRT_ERS].[ID] from DSRT_TEMP table and insert only filtered records.

```
INSERT INTO DSRT_ERS
SELECT *
FROM DSRT_TEMP
WHERE  [DSRT_TEMP].[ID] NOT IN (Select [DSRT_ERS].[ID] FROM [DSRT_ERS]
                                 WHERE [DSRT_ERS].[ID] IS NOT NULL)
```

There are two options, you have `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` suggested by @deoeth.
Keep in mind While choose one.

If the sub-query (inner query) returns small amount of data, `[NOT] IN` operator may give better performance.

If the sub-query returns large volume of data `[NOT] EXISTS` operator is preferable.

You can also use Left Outer Join, if you want to get rid of suquery

```
INSERT INTO DSRT_ERS
SELECT *
FROM DSRT_TEMP 
     LEFT Outer JOIN [DSRT_ERS] ON [DSRT_TEMP].[ID] = [DSRT_ERS].[ID]
WHERE  [DSRT_ERS].[ID] IS NULL
```

Comment: This will fail if there's a NULL returned in the NOT IN, at least add a `WHERE [DSRT_ERS].[ID] IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Eek. A nullable ID. I'd think that is not very likely, but OP's table seems to allow it.

Comment: @GolezTrol just for safe reason, better to take precautions

Comment: @GolezTrol: Better check the definition: of the target columns: **Name ID, Type Text, AllowZeroLength: True, Required: False** :-)

Comment: Yes, I saw the definition. It surprised me that ID is not required and if ID is really an ID, I would choose to fix the table structure rather than adding `NOT NULL` to the subselect. Nevertheless, it prevents issues with the current table structure, so well spotted, @dnoeth.

Comment: @GolezTrol
The person who built the DB before me create no identifiers into it and how it's set up I can't actually correct it..
There are null ID values so thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you want to insert only rows which don't exist yet in the target.

You can't reference the target table directly in the SELECT. Change it to a NOT EXISTS instead:

```
INSERT INTO DSRT_ERS
SELECT *
FROM DSRT_TEMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (
   SELECT * FROM DSRT_ERS
   WHERE [DSRT_ERS].[ID] =[DSRT_TEMP].[ID]
 );
```